# web sharing for vhosts?

Tags: macos, apache, webserver

I'd like to be able to share websites I'm developing with other users in my network using Web Sharing. I don't develop in my 'Sites' folder though, I have a separate folder for all my projects.

(Note: web sharing is working generally. If I visit `http://[my-local-ip-address]/~[myusername]` it shows the default local Site that I never touch.)

e.g. I use apache's httpd-vhosts.conf file and /etc/hosts to setup local domains that can be accessed by me like so:

`http://mytestsite`

So.. can I configure OS X Lion & apache to allow other to see them around the LAN like this?

`http://[my-local-ip-address]/~mytestsite`

Thanks!
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can configure Mac OS X 10.7, aka Lion, to serve multiple web sites using URLs like `http://[my-local-ip-address]/~mytestsite`.

The format of URL you suggest can be achieved by creating a new user for each site, and storing the web pages in that user's Sites folder.

Alternatively, you could create subfolders within your site's folder:

- `http://[my-local-ip-address]/~[myusername]/site1`
- `http://[my-local-ip-address]/~[myusername]/site2`
- `http://[my-local-ip-address]/~[myusername]/site3`

Going another step further, you can customise the [Apache httpd 2 configuration files](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/configuring.html) at `/etc/apache2/users/[myusername]` to tweak the set up to your exact needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you have all of the projects in a single folder just set Apache's `DocumentRoot` in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` to directory.

Or you can just put the project folders in `/Library/WebServer/Documents`.